# Query SQL Server table using EF Core convert varchar to Unicode in Where clause

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, unicode, entity-framework-core, varchar

I am trying to access some data from a SQL Server database using EF Core like this:

```
var result = _dbContext.FreightStatusUpdate
                       .Where(w => w.AwbNumber == "049-2154784")
                       .ToList();
```

The underlying query that gets generated (in output windows) is

```
SELECT [m].[ID], [m].[AIRPORT_CODE], [m].[APPOINTMENT_NO], [m].[AWB_NUMBER], [m].[CREATED_BY], [m].[CREATED_DATE], [m].[CUSTOM_STATUS], [m].[TYPE], [m].[UPDATED_BY], [m].[UPDATED_DATE]
FROM [FMG].[FreightStatusUpdate] AS [m]
WHERE [m].[AWB_NUMBER] = N'049-2154784'
```

All columns in the table (including `AWB_NUMBER`) are of type `varchar` (not `NVarchar`), but `N` (Unicode) is prefixed in the `WHERE` clause, which is causing a performance hit in the application.

Column is defined like below in the Model.

```
[Column("AWB_NUMBER")]
public string AwbNumber { get; set; }
```

How can I avoid this, and query the same information, without Unicode conversion for `varchar` types, and keep the `nvarchar` as `N` (Unicode)?

Comment: How is the column defined in the model? Possibly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341783/entity-framework-data-annotations-set-stringlength-varchar

Comment: @Charlieface just updated the question, pls chk