# Code First data types and max characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, ef-code-first

I noticed that `Code First` makes from every string a `nvarchar` data type in the `SQL database`. And the max amount of characters are set on `MAX`.

How can I influence this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[MaxLength(10)]
public string PropertyName {get;set;}
```

Comment: Hi, what about nvarchar? What can I do against that?

Comment: You could use `[Column(TypeName = "varchar")]`. If you want to set it globally to all string types, see this [page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109170/ef-code-first-globally-set-varchar-mapping-over-nvarchar)